# Redirect back without losing get parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I writing simple MVC web page. I will be used by very limited number of users so I don't need and I don't want to care about many standards things.

I have some controller listing some entities. User can filter it, can go to other pages. It all adds get parameters, i.e. `?site=3&id_gt=14`. This is `Index` action of the controller.

There are some actions on that list which I'm handling using `POST`. For example there could be action `Delete`. Inside code of `Delete` action in the controller I'm processing request and at the and I'm redirecting back to `Index` action:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(/* some parameters*/)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(/* some model*/)
    {
        //deleting code
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm losing `GET` parameters from `Index`. Is there any easy way to return sth from `Delete` controller which would tell the browser that it should reload current page with all `GET` parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it in simple way:

`return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);`

It gets `url` from request and redirect back to it with all `GET` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Redhead is correct. You can also use the TempData collection that preserves data through a redirection but internally, not in the query string. It essentially uses session under the hood but it doesn't preserve a value for more than 1 redirection.

Answer (score 0):

When calling         RedirectToAction()        you can use the overload [RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues
)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to add your parameters as routeValues in an annonymous object.

E.G.

```
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{Parameter1 = (somevalue), Parameter2 = (somevalue)});
```